# How do I see the contents of the dev server after bundling from webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

My understanding is that webpack in dev mode will put all your imported somewhere and then serve your bundle.js to the client. When the code inside bundle.js asks for a css file, the css-loader would have been configured previously to set up the file path for your client to ask the server to load the stylesheet. I want to check this somehow and ensure that my sever has the stylesheet. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can check which files are being served by the dev server by going to /webpack-dev-server route. For example, http://localhost:9000/webpack-dev-server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `webpack-dev-server` your bundle is loaded into memory, not written to disk. If you run the `webpack` cli instead it will put your assets into the output directory. You can easily check to see if what you expect to be output is there.

If you have installed webpack locally to your project you can run it from your root dir with:

```
`node_modules/.bin/webpack --config <path/to/webpack.config.js>`
```

If webpack.config.js is in the same dir then you don't need the --config flag.

This is what you do when you deploy to production since `webpack-dev-server` is designed for development only.